# Determining the size of an object allocated on the heap

Tags: debugging, windbg

As part of an assignment, dealing with the operation aurora vulnerability, I am supposed to determine the size of C++ classes allocated on the heap.

I used:

```
0:017> !heap -p -a <address of the class I am researching>
```

And got:

```
address 047dcf08 found in
  _DPH_HEAP_ROOT @ 12d1000
  in busy allocation (DPH_HEAP_BLOCK:     UserAddr     UserSize -    VirtAddr   VirtSize)
                             4501270:      47dcf08           f8 -     47dc000       2000
```

According to the user size, the object is `0xf8` in size, but are there any header/trailer bytes that need to be subtracted to get the actual size of the class in this allocation block ?

Answer (score 2):

No, `UserSize` is the size that was sent to the allocator.

```
malloc(0x100); // usersize 100
```

The obvious exception to this would be if you're using a custom heap allocator built on top of the standard heap allocator.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer but windbg has a nice command that *lets you "decipher"* the answer to most of these question *by yourself* the name of the command is `.ocommand`

an example showing how you can ascertain what usersize points to using this command

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void dbg (PCHAR cmdstr , PVOID value) {
    char buff[0x300] = {0};
    sprintf_s(buff,cmdstr,value);
    OutputDebugStringA(buff);
    return ;
}
int main(void) {
    printf (
        "This is a windbg .ocommand Example\n"
        "This command can be leveraged to execute windbg commands \n"
        "For example command !heap -p -a is performed on allocated heap\n"
        "Output of !heap -p -a <address> can be viewed in windbg \n"
        "issue .ocommand myjick in windbg prior to running this exe\n"
        "or run this exe with windbg -c \".ocommand myjick\" ocommand.exe\n"
        );
    HANDLE hHeap = NULL;   
    if((hHeap = GetProcessHeap() ) != NULL)     {
        for (int i = 1 ; i< 6; i++)  {
            PCHAR mem[6] = {0};
            if (( mem[i] = (PCHAR)HeapAlloc(hHeap,0,0x101*i) ) != NULL)   {
                dbg("myjick !heap -p -a %x ;g;\n\n",mem[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; //all the allocated heaps need to be freed
}
```

output for the above code

**cdb -c ".ocommand myjick ;g;q" ocommand.exe**

```
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.ocommand myjick ;g;q'
Treat output prefixed with 'myjick ' as a command

This is a windbg .ocommand Example
This command can be leveraged to execute windbg commands
For example command !heap -p -a is performed on allocated heap
Output of !heap -p -a <address> can be viewed in windbg
issue .ocommand myjick in windbg prior to running this exe
or run this exe with windbg -c ".ocommand myjick" ocommand.exe 

    address 001537e8 found in
    _HEAP @ 150000
      HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
        001537e0 0024 0000  [07]   001537e8    00101 - (busy)    
    address 00153908 found in
    _HEAP @ 150000
      HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
        00153900 0044 0000  [07]   00153908    00202 - (busy)    
    address 00153b28 found in
    _HEAP @ 150000
      HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
        00153b20 0064 0000  [07]   00153b28    00303 - (busy)    
    address 00153e48 found in
    _HEAP @ 150000
      HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
        00153e40 0084 0000  [07]   00153e48    00404 - (busy)    
    address 00154268 found in
    _HEAP @ 150000
      HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
        00154260 00a4 0000  [07]   00154268    00505 - (busy)
```